# Why I use 'on' in data.table can make "NA"

Tags: r, data.table

First,I make a data.table.

```
    set.seed(100)
    a <- data.table(x = sample(c(1:1000),100000,replace = TRUE),
                y = sample(letters,100000,replace = TRUE),
                z = 1:100000)
```

I use one method `a[x >= 900 & y == 'b', .N]`,then the result is 389.

Then I use another method `a[.(c(900:max(x)),'b'), .N, on = .(x,y)]`,the result is 394.

I find that the second method can make 'NA'

`a[.(c(900:max(x)),'b'), on = .(x,y)][is.na(z)]`

WHY??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we use `nomatch=0`, the NA elements will be gone

```
a[.(c(900:max(x)),'b'), .N, on = .(x,y), nomatch = 0]
#[1] 389
```

The reason is that we are taking the sequence from 900 to the `max` value of 'x'.  So some elements are missing.  For example

```
a[.(c(900:max(x)),'b'),  on = .(x,y)][is.na(z)]
#    x y  z
#1: 948 b NA
#2: 958 b NA
#3: 975 b NA
#4: 984 b NA
#5: 986 b NA
```

which will result in `NA` elements for 'z' as we are doing a `left` join.

The reason is that these elements are missing for the combination

```
c(948, 958, 975, 984, 986) %in% a[x > 900 & y == "b"][, sort(unique(x))]
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: Yes,`a[x == 948,unique(y)]`,"b" is not in the result.Thank you!